# haml rails - why can't i wrap a form input field in a div?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, haml

I understand haml indentation controls what is nested within what.

Does the number of indentation spaces matter? I'm using 2 spaces rather than 3 or 4. I would imagine as long as it's consistent, it shouldn't matter. Does it matter if it's tabs or spaces?

Why does the following label and text_field cause a crash when i try to wrap it in a .form-group div?

```
    = form_for @character, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f|
      - if @character.errors.any?
        #error_explanation
          %h2= "#{pluralize(@character.errors.count, "error")} prohibited this character from being saved:"
          %ul
            - @character.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
              %li= msg

      .form-group
        = f.label :name
        = f.text_field :name

      = f.label :image
      = f.file_field :image 

      = f.submit
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/):

> Haml’s indentation can be made up of one or more tabs or spaces.
>   However, indentation must be consistent within a given document. Hard
>   tabs and spaces can’t be mixed, and the same number of tabs or spaces
>   must be used throughout.

I think your error is caused by the fact that elements under `#error_explanation` are indented too far.  Pull them over to the left and see if it now works.  If not, add the stacktrace to the question.

Comment: i used spaces only and it worked now.
The #error_explanation didn't seem to cause any problems as is. But it should be - #error_explanation, right?, since starting a line with a # doesn't actually count as a commented out line.

Comment: That's correct.  `#error_explanation` would result in `<div id="error_explanation"></div>`